# How to pass a string parameter to evaluateJavascript in android

Tags: android, android-webview, android-webview-javascript

I tried to pass a string parameter to the web app javascript code. It's failed while passing a variable with the string value. But it works when we hardcode the data. Please let me know what's wrong with this.

Working hardcoded code:

```
mWebview.evaluateJavascript("cm.setData('N051783')", new ValueCallback<String>() {

     @Override
     public void onReceiveValue(String value3) {

          Log.d(" setData Return Value"," setData Return... "+value3);

     }
});
```

Not working code with string variable

```
mWebview.evaluateJavascript("cm.setData("+sub_data+")", new ValueCallback<String>() {

       @Override
       public void onReceiveValue(String value3) {

            Log.d(" sub_data Return Value"," sub_data Return... "+value3);

       }
});
```

Comment: Fixed the above issue by this  "common.ContinueInspectionOffline('"+sub_url_vin+"')". Will help anyone future

Comment: Can you add that in answer. I did not understand.

Answer (score 1):

### You are probably missing ""

My JavaScript function at com.UserProfile

```
function setUserName(name){
   alert('username is ' + name)
}
```

**How to call it from Java**

```
mWebview.evaluateJavascript("com.UserProfile.setUserName("Rohit")",null);
```

### How to pass the parameter?

You need to concatenate " with parameter. " is a special character. This is how you can concatenate " in a String.

Here is an example:

```
String username = "Rohit";
String func = com.UserProfile.setUserName(\""+ username + "\")";

mWebview.evaluateJavascript(func, null);
```

**You can use StringBuilder to concatenate as well as"**

Let's break it down line by line;

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("com.UserProfile.setUserName")   //com.UserProfile.setUserName
  .append("(")                             //com.UserProfile.setUserName(
  .append("\"")                            //com.UserProfile.setUserName("
  .append(username)                        //com.UserProfile.setUserName("Rohit
  .append("\"")                            //com.UserProfile.setUserName("Rohit"
  .append(")")                             //com.UserProfile.setUserName("Rohit")

 String func = sb.toString();

 mWebview.evaluateJavascript(func, null);
```